# how to create a new table from `describe` statement in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a new table with rows of the column names.  Essentially, I want to put the output of a `decribe` statement into a new table, so that I can use a `where` clause to only extract certain column names.  I'm using sparksql.

How do I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a describe statement, do you mean MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

No need to create an additional table just use either [SHOW COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html) command instead of describe with filter, or query [information_schema.columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) table with a select.